# Laravel external Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4

I do my authentication via a restful API which I validate, if its successful it gives me the username and i take that and try to login to my Laravel app. When I finish logging in, it seems to work. However, It doesn't seem to be keeping session as I navigate around the site I am still authenticated as a guest.

```
public function login(){
    // I do a guzzle request that gives me the value of $response['username']
    $Username = $response['username'];
    $user = User::where('username','thomc')->first();
    Auth::login($user);
    return view('home');
}
```

This is my User model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'UserDetails';
}
```

My table:

- Username
- Email
- First_Name
- Last_Name
- BA
- Facebook_ID
- Google_ID

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a test change, but you're not using the $Username, instead searching for the user `thomc`. Another thing to note would be check if the user with username exists in the database, if not the $user returned would be null. Try login with id as well.

```
$username = $response['username'];
$user = User::where('username', $username)->firstOrFail();
Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
```

Also make sure all the routes are wrapped with the `web` middleware, and appropriate `auth` and `guest` middleware on routes as needed.